# Scraping $ parsing multiple html tables with the same URL (beautifulsoup & selenium)

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, html-table, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

i'm trying to scrape the full HTML table from this site:
https://www.iscc-system.org/certificates/all-certificates/

My code is as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.iscc-system.org/certificates/all-certificates/'
browser = webdriver.Chrome('/home/giuseppe/bin/chromedriver')
browser.get(url)

csvfile = open('Scrape_certificates', 'a')     

dfs = pd.read_html('https://www.iscc-system.org/certificates/all-certificates/', header=0)

for i in range(1,10):
    for df in dfs:
    df.to_csv(csvfile, header=False)
    link_next_page = browser.find_element_by_id('table_1_next')
    link_next_page.click()
    time.sleep(4)
    dfs = pd.read_html(browser.current_url)

csvfile.close()
```

The above code is only for the first 10 pages of the full table as an example.
The problem is that the output is always the same first table repeated 10 times, although by clicking the 'next table' button the actual table gets updated (at least if I see the webpage), I'm unable to get the real new data from the following table. I get always the same data from the first table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you are reading the URL with pandas not the page source. This will fetch the page new not read the Selenium generated source. Secondly you want to limit the reading to the table with the id = table_1. Try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.iscc-system.org/certificates/all-certificates/'
browser = webdriver.Chrome('/home/giuseppe/bin/chromedriver')
browser.get(url)

csvfile = open('Scrape_certificates', 'a')

for i in range(1,10):
    dfs = pd.read_html(browser.page_source, attrs = {'id': 'table_1'})
    for df in dfs:
        df.to_csv(csvfile, header=False)
    link_next_page = browser.find_element_by_id('table_1_next')
    link_next_page.click()
    time.sleep(4)

csvfile.close()
```

You will need to remove or filter out line 10 from each result as it is the navigation.